# Recorrer array 1 dimension, codigo intermedio(3 direcciones) C++

Tags: c++, array, matrices

Buenas noches, estoy programando una sopa de letras en c++ con codigo intermedio o tres direcciones para después pasarlo a ensamblador GUI TASM. Lo que debe hacer el programa es imprimir un array unidimensional con las letras, e ir moviendome por el array con las flechas y al oprimir enter sobre una letra, si es una de las aceptadas cambiarla de color.

En codigo intermedio no puedo usar las coordenadas (x,y) como en una matriz bidimensional, en este caso se hace mediante la formula f(x,y) = x + Zy ; donde "x" es la columna, "y" es la fila y "Z" es el ancho de la matriz.

Mi duda surge, en como implementar la funcionalidad de ir recorriendo el array y al ser una letra aceptada cambiarla de color. Mi teoría es tener tres array, uno para mostrar las letras, otro con los valores de los colores y un último con las posiciones que son aceptadas. Actualmente cambio los colores basandome en un array que ya tiene los valores de colores cambiados.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, especificamente a poder ir recorriendo el array y cambiar los colores si es letra aceptada, muy agradecido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void gotoxy(int column, int line);
void drawStaticSprite(int sprite[][10]);
void drawStaticSprite3Dir();

int sleepTime = 100;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

char sop3dir2[100]=  {'M','M','L','E','E','N','A','E','V','E',
                      'E','R','H','O','N','G','O','S','T','R',
                      'X','X','O','T','I','R','R','A','C','A',
                      'I','S','A','P','P','O','T','A','P','S',
                      'C','C','M','L','A','A','I','Z','O','T',
                      'O','A','A','U','A','N','U','L','P','U',
                      'S','O','M','B','R','E','R','O','M','P',
                      'C','N','E','A','R','R','I','I','O','O',
                      'W','O','J','E','N','O','C','P','Z','E',
                      'A','A','Z','A','A','L','N','Y','T','D'};

int Colores1[100] =  {15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      15,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,14,14,
                      15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,14,14,
                      14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
                      14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int myChar;

drawStaticSprite3Dir();
do {
    myChar = getch();

    if (myChar == 224)
     {
        myChar = getch();
        }
     else
     {
            if (myChar == 72)//Fecla Arriba
        {
            y=y-1;
        }
        else if (myChar == 80)//Fecla Abajo
        {
            y=y+1;
        }
        else if (myChar == 75)//Flecha Izquierda
        {
            x=x-1;
        }
        else if (myChar == 77)//Flecha Derecha
        {
            x=x+1;
        }
        else if (myChar == 13) //Si es enter grabar posicion
        {
        //colores(y,x);

        }
}
} while (myChar != 27);
getch();
return 0;
}
void drawStaticSprite3Dir() {
int startX;
int startY;
int x;
int y;
int t1;
int t2;

startX = 0;
startY = 0;

x = 0;
l5:
if (x < 10) goto l0;
goto l1;

l0:
y = 0;
l4:
if (y < 10) goto l2;
goto l3;

l2:
t1 =  startY + y;
t2 =  startX + x;

gotoxy( t2,t1);

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Colores1[x + 
(10*y)]);

printf("%c", putchar(sop3dir2[x+(10*y)]));

y = y + 1;
goto l4;

l3:
x = x + 1;
goto l5;

l1:
return;
}

void gotoxy( int column, int line ) {
COORD coord;
coord.X = column;
coord.Y = line;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ),coord);
}
```

Comment: No acabo de entender tu problema. Tu lógica es adecuada y los cálculos que haces para posicionar la coordenada son correctos. ¿cuál es el problema en concreto?

Comment: El problema es que no logro entender la forma de enviar las coordenadas al momento de mover las flechas para posicionarme en alguna parte del array.

Comment: Sigo sin entenderte, las coordenadas no hay que enviarlas a ningún sitio: tan sólo hay que usarlas para refrescar la información en pantalla. Dado que las coordenadas ya las tienes y las actualizas mediante teclado (con los `if` `else` encadenados), pinta tu cuadrícula basándote en la celda activa (la que apunten las coordenadas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi duda surge, en como poder recorrer ese array de una dimension, con las flechas del teclado, ya que aun no entiendo muy bien como deberia mandar las coordenadas segun oprima las flechas

En un array bidimensional tienes dos coordenadas **siempre**, a saber `x` e `y`.

De lo que trata tu ejercicio es de implementar un array bidimiensional en un array unidimensional. En este caso, dado que tu vas a tratarlo como un array bidimensional, seguirás teniendo dos dimensiones: `x` e `y`. La complejidad se encuentra en cómo relacionar ambas coordenadas con una posición concreta del array.

Para hacer esto último ya te están dando la fórmula `posicion = x + Z*y`, donde `Z` indica el número de columnas de la matriz. ¿Cual es la razón de ser de esta fórmula?

En una matriz los datos los tienes estructurados así:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Y, para acceder al elemento (1,2) basta con hacer `array[1][2]`... simple y facil de entender.

Sin embargo en un array unidimensional los mismos datos se encontrarán estructurados de la siguiente manera:

```
| fila 0  | fila 1  | fila 2  |
| 1  2  3 | 4  5  6 | 7  8  9 |
```

Así, para acceder al elemento con coordenadas(1,2) tienes que hacer la siguiente transformación (recuerda que en C++ los índices empiezan en 0):

```
pos = col + Z * fil = 2 + 3 * 1 = 5

| fila 0  | fila 1  | fila 2  |
| 1  2  3 | 4  5  6 | 7  8  9 |
                  ^ (1,2)
```

Puedes comprobar entonces que **siempre** vas a necesitar dos dimensiones. Lo único que cambia es el mecanismo mediante el cual accedes a las posiciones del array.

Ahora bien... tu programa tiene algunos errores:

```
do {
  myChar = getch();

  if (myChar == 224) // <----
  {
    myChar = getch();
  }
  else
  {
```

Fíjate que, al presionar una flecha, efectivamente se recuperará el código 224 y entonces el programa recuperará el código de la flecha pulsada, pero **no se hace nada con ese código**... ya que las flechas se procesan en en `else` y, en consecuencia, nunca se actualizará la posición.

Tienes que tener algo así:

```
if (myChar == 224)
{
  myChar = getch();

  if (myChar == 72)//Fecla Arriba
  // ...
```

Y nota también que te faltaría llamar a `gotoxy` para actualizar la posición.

```
if (myChar == 224)
{
  myChar = getch();
  if (myChar == 72)//Fecla Arriba
  {
    y=y-1;
  }
  else if (myChar == 80)//Fecla Abajo
  {
    y=y+1;
  }
  else if (myChar == 75)//Flecha Izquierda
  {
    x=x-1;
  }
  else if (myChar == 77)//Flecha Derecha
  {
    x=x+1;
  }

  gotoxy(x,y);
}
else if (myChar == 13) //Si es enter grabar posicion
{
  //colores(y,x);
}
```

Y, en serio... ¿es necesario usar `goto`? Eso en ensamblador pase que sea necesario, pero ¿en C++? ¿En pleno siglo XXI? sinceramente... hazte un favor a tí mismo y borra toda referencia a `goto` de tu código. Si de verdad te gusta `goto` entonces programa en ensamblador...

No se, yo prefiero encontrarme esto:

```
void drawStaticSprite3Dir() {
  for( int x=0; x<10; x++ )
  {
    for( int y=0; y<10; y++ )
    {
      gotoxy(x,y);
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                              Colores1[x+(10*y)]);
      putchar(sop3dir2[x+(10*y)]);
    }
  }
}
```

...que entiendo lo que hace a la primera, a esto otro:

```
void drawStaticSprite3Dir() {
  int startX;
  int startY;
  int x;
  int y;
  int t1;
  int t2;

  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;

  x = 0;
l5:
  if (x < 10) goto l0;
  goto l1;

l0:
  y = 0;
l4:
  if (y < 10) goto l2;
  goto l3;

l2:
  t1 =  startY + y;
  t2 =  startX + x;

  gotoxy( t2,t1);

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Colores1[x + 
      (10*y)]);

  printf("%c", putchar(sop3dir2[x+(10*y)]));

  y = y + 1;
  goto l4;

l3:
  x = x + 1;
  goto l5;

l1:
  return;
}
```

¿y tu?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, de hecho ese gotoxy que debo llamar al momento de presionar las flechas, es el que no logro hacer funcionar, si pudieras ayudarme muchas gracias . Y disculpa por no escribir en el mensaje principal que la razón de hacer el código de esa manera, es que debo pasarlo a ensamblador después, GUI TASM.

Comment: @raintrooper no se a tí, pero el código que te he puesto en la respuesta a mi me funciona. Respecto a traducirlo después a ensamblador... yo no aprovecharía para hacer código que funcionase en ambos casos porque te vas a volver loco depurando el código C++

Comment: @raintrooper por cierto, te sugiero que edites la pregunta para que refleje fielmente tus problemas... así será más probable que recibas otras respuestas

Comment: Gracias por el consejo eferion, editaré la pregunta. Ahora en lo que debo trabajar es en moverme por el array y al dar enter si la letra donde me posiciono es una de las aceptadas cambiarla de color. Actualmente  esta ya grabado en el array los numero 15 que son los que cambian el color a blanco.